# Why does this controller seem to "hold onto state" even between tests?

Tags: ember.js

I'm writing a simple qunit test that has a controller setup w/ a few items in an array

```
App.UploadController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  to_upload: Ember.A([])
});
```

I add stuff to this "to_upload" array and verify it between tests. One issue I've found that that if I don't "manually clear it" like this in my test "tear down" it holds onto this state (even with an App.reset() being called in each teardown (calling destroy).

```
App.__container__.lookup("controller:upload").clear_files()
```

(the clear files is a simple monkey patch I added in my test helper -not production code)

```
App.UploadController.reopen
  clear_files: function() {
    this.get('to_upload').clear();
  }
```

Here is my tear down for the qunit tests

```
module "/upload",
  teardown: function() {
    App.reset()
    App.__container__.lookup("controller:upload").clear_files()
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably related to the fact that assigning an array to a property in the class definition makes it a class property and not an instance property.  I'm not sure if this is documented somewhere, I've read it before a few times though.  I'll update with documentation if I can find it.

Until then you can probably prove my theory by modifying the code to look like this.

```
App.UploadController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  init: function(){
    this.set('to_upload', Em.A([]));
    this._super();
  },
  to_upload: null
});
```

You can read about it in step 6 here http://codebrief.com/2012/03/eight-ember-dot-js-gotchas-with-workarounds/

I'm pretty sure this should be put somewhere in the docs, I'm not sure where the most obvious would be though.

Comment: I should really get you on retainer :)